# Why are the Warriors called the dubs or Golden State is referred to as dub city?

Tags: terminology

Urban dictionary doesn't tell me anything about why the Warriors are called the Dubs or why Golden State is called Dub City.

Comment: From [Wiki Answers](http://www.answers.com/Q/Why_are_the_golden_state_warriors_called_the_dubs): Why are the golden state warriors called the dubs? ... "Dub" is short for the letter W, which starts the word Warriors. Fans like to abbreviate things with a first initial, but it's cumbersome to say dub-ell-yous. >> Assuming this to be true, 'Dub City' is a transferred usage.

Comment: For the next two or three years, the Golden State Warriors will continue to play their home games in the city of Oakland, California. Oakland is not widely known as "Dub City," as far as I know (and I live practically next door to it); rather, it is familiarly known as "Oak-town." "Golden State" was adopted when the team moved from San Francisco (the glamour city of the Bay Area) to Oakland (the original "there's no there there" city, according to Gertrude Stein, who grew up in Oakland) in 1971. I expect that when they return to SF in a few years they'll be the San Francisco Warriors again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Dubs" is a shorter way of saying "Ws." The full pronunciation of "Ws" would be "double yooz," so it's abbreviated to "dubz" as a slangy way of referring to the team name (Warriors):

> Warriors -> Ws (double yooz) -> Dubs

By the same token, "Dub City"->"W" City->Warriors City

Similarly, George W. Bush was/is sometimes referred to by the nickname "[Dubya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_W._Bush)," in reference to his "W" middle name (Walker).

(One other example of a "W" name being shortened to "dub(s)": Buffalo Wild Wings is referred to as [B-Dubs](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=B+Dubs).)